# this.Close() won't work

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I have a windows forms app (c# 4.0) and the "X" button won't close the form, and this.close() won't do it either.

Other forms work fine, yet when I copy the designer over to a new form, it breaks that form too!

any clues?

Comment: Have you written any code for the Form_Closing event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so... apparently *this* makes it work (creating a closing event, and putting in the following code)

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    this.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: There must be some code somewhere that's stopping the form from closing naturally.

Comment: Try e.Cancel = false; instead.